# Change which key opens BIOS during boot

Tags: bios

Is it possible to change what key launches the BIOS menu during boot?
I am trying to use a netbooter to install a specific OS on my laptop. In order to access the netbooter, I have to press F12 at a specific time during boot. However, on the laptop I am currently using, F12 is the key that opens the BIOS. Whenever I try to access the netbooter, the BIOS gets opened instead.

Ideally, I want my device to open the BIOS when F2 or Del is pressed, and leave F12 open for netbooting. Is this possible? Can I change which key launches the BIOS?

Thanks

Comment: If you are hardcore enough to take bios dump and disassemble it, modify the key sequence, reassemble it and flash it back into the bios... am not saying its impossible, its a sure fire way to cause grief and headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your BIOS supports it natively I don't think there is an easy way to do it.  The open source BIOS Libreboot might be able to do it, but it will be a project.

Answer (score 0):

Some BIOSes have an option to change the keys for setup or the boot menu. Look in the BIOS setup. If the option is there, you can. If the option isn't there, you can't.